# UITextField becomes first responder by itself...?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield

**This happens only on device and not on simulator..**

I have two custom views and both have a UITextField in them(Child1 and Child2).
Both these views are placed on another UIView (Say viewA).
Now my requirement is such that when text is entered in one of the textfield I need to clear the other text fields content, so in the textFieldDidChange: method I inform viewA and than it iterates over its subview finds Child1 and sets its properties. But as soon as I access the textField of this Child1 to enable its userInteraction or and set its text to nil. This textfield now becomes the first responder.

I am not really sure why it does that. You can look at the below code to get more info.

Method inside viewA:

```
  for (UIView *view in [self subviews])
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[ChildView class]])
        {
            ChildView *concernedCustomerView = (ChildView *)view;
            if (concernedCustomerView.typeOfCompartment == CompartmentTypeNone)
            {
                [concernedCustomerView.checkBoxButton setSelected:NO];
                [concernedCustomerView.countSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
                concernedCustomerView.countTextField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                concernedCustomerView.countTextField.alpha = 1.0f;
                concernedCustomerView.countTextField.text = nil;
            }
        }
    }
```

Method inside custom Child View

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange:(id)sender
{
    NSString *note = _countTextField.text;
    note = [note stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    //If we are checking note for nil it should be before calling trimming white space
    if (note && note.length > 0)
    {
        [_checkBoxButton setSelected:YES];
        if (note.length == 3 && note.integerValue == 999)
        {
            [_countSwitch setOn:YES animated:YES];
            _countTextField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            _countTextField.alpha = 0.5f;
            _countTextField.text = nil;
//           [_countSwitch sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [_checkBoxButton setSelected:NO];
    }

    if ([self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(ChildViewDelegate)] &&
        [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(adjustStateOfOtherControls:andCheckBoxStatus:)])
    {
        [self.delegate adjustStateOfOtherControls:_typeOfCompartment andCheckBoxStatus:_checkBoxButton.selected];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not set the view object to nil because they are alive and your controller is still active,
try to set  `_countTextField.text = @"";` so that your textfield become empty.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggest:

1) Instead of manual iterate subviews you can assign tag to child views and uitextfields e.g:

```
child1View.tag = 100;
child2View.tag = 200;
...
textField1.tag = 10;
textField2.tag = 20;
```

then get child references from parent viewA by:

```
 UIView *child1View = [viewA viewWithTag:100];
 UIView *child2View = [viewA viewWithTag:200];
```

2) Set child views textfield delegate to a common viewcontroller

3) Handle one single

```
  - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

4) Iniside this method check

```
if(textField.tag==10)
{
  do stuff
}
else if(textfield.tag==20)
{
  do other stuff
}
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Why would this work and not the one I wrote..? please backup your answer with some reasoning...