# Does UITextField objects become first responder by default when touched, without explicit implementation?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm doing [Angela's iOS bootcamp course](https://www.udemy.com/course/ios-13-app-development-bootcamp/), and currently doing the Clima Project which fetches and shows the temperature data.

[image: App Screen]

During earlier phase of the project tutorials I called the `becomeFirstResponder()` using the `@IBOutlet weak var searchTextField: UITextField!` object as soon as the view loaded.

Now I started to implement the location fetching on my own, and thought of making the `UITextField`  object first responder only when the user touches the `UITextField`. I wanted to detect when the user touched the `UITextField`.

First I've tried using the `textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_:)`, but that resulted in the runtime error.

Then I created a `IBAction` function using the same `UITextField`and used that to trigger the first responder. This time it worked as I expected. When I opened the app, the keyboard didn't show, and when I touched the `UITextField`, it worked.

I removed the `IBAction` function and the same behaviour continued.

Does the `UITextField` become first responder implicitly when the user touches the field?

(Did read the [UITextField becomes first responder by itself...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309412/uitextfield-becomes-first-responder-by-itself). My problem wasn't related to a UITextField object becoming first responder when accessing that object programatically.)

Comment: could you plz try -->   DispatchQueue.main.async { textfield.becomeFirstResponder() } , textfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(method), for: .touchDown) , textfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(method), for: .allEvents)

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar Why?

Comment: Don't you want get tap method on the textfield? for getting becomefirstresponser?

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar You don't need any of that code. If you want to know when a text field becomes the first responder you just need to implement the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` delegate method.

Comment: I understand that @MaziarSaadatfar. My doubt was just if it automatically will always try to become the first responder when/if the user taps the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr - Yes

Full answer:

When a touch event is sent to a view like `UITextField` or `UITextView`, the  view does attempt to become first responder. If the responder chain allows the view to become first responder, then it does become first responder and the keyboard will be shown.

The documentation for [`UIResponder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder) actually answers your question with the following:

> When the user taps a `UITextField` and `UITextView` object onscreen, the view becomes the first responder and displays its input view, which is the system keyboard.

Though that does assume there is nothing preventing the view from becoming first responder. I recommend reading the documentation for `UIResponder` since it is quite important in regards to your question. This includes a link to [Using responders and the responder chain to handle events](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/using_responders_and_the_responder_chain_to_handle_events).

When a `UITextField` or `UITextView` does become first responder, the corresponding delegate method, if implemented, will be called.

You only need to explicitly call `becomeFirstResponder()` on a text field, for example, if you want the field to be the first responder and have the keyboard appear without the user having to tap on the field. If you only want a text field to become active when the user taps on it, then no code is needed to make that happen (other than to avoid writing code to prevent it from happening).

The `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_:)` should only be implemented if you have logic in your app where you wish to prevent a text field from becoming first responder under certain conditions. Maybe you have a data entry screen that needs to be read-only at the moment. Among the various ways to do that, you could return `false` for `textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_:)`.

Also note that `becomeFirstResponder()` returns a `Bool`. A call to `becomeFirstResponder()` is a request that may not be granted. This can fail if the current first responder fails to resign first responder, for example.